# How to `export PATH` from C

Tags: bash, shell, c

Wondering how to accomplish one of these things from C, so that it persists like it would from `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
export PS1="$ "
```

Wondering if I should use the [`execl` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209141/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-built-in-command-with-a-c-function/19209390#19209390) sort of like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void) {
  return execl("/bin/export", "...", NULL);
}
```

Or if there is another idiomatic C way to accomplish this properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't export variables from a program to the parent shell, because it is not possible to modify the environment of another process.

If you want to set up a child process, see `man setenv` or `man execve`.

**Edit**

The difference is that `.bashrc` is executed by the shell itself, not by a subprocess of the shell. As it is executed by the shell, it can modify the environment of the shell.

The only way around this is to create commands that will be executed by the shell:

```
main ()
{
    printf ("PATH=/dir\n");
}
```

Then in the Shell execute the output from that command:

```
$(./myenv)
```

Or

```
./myenv > /tmp/file
source /tmp/file
```

But it is still the shell that modifies its own environment, it just does so by executing commands that are generated from some program.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want to create a child process.

Comment: I didn't say you would, just that there is a way to set `PATH` for a child. On the other hand, there is no way to change `PATH` for another process, including the parent. So what you want to do is impossible.

Comment: It seems like there must be _some_ way, because I could write to a file ~/.bashrc that PATH snippet and that seems like it would work, so maybe there is another approach that I am not familiar with but this question is about. Thank you.

Comment: @LancePollard Exactly how are you envisioning this C program being run, and what processes’ environments do you want it to affect?

Comment: I don't have much of a preference, I just want to be able to in some way from C set an environment variable, and the C process will be long lasting.

Comment: @LancePollard I think you're misunderstanding how environment variables work. Environment variables are private to each process, so setting an environment variable in a C program only affects that C program, and any other programs that it forks and/or execs. The way that ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile work is that every new shell that spawns runs one or the other of them, and thus gets those environment variables defined in the new shell. Those env variables *must be created anew for every new (parent) shell*, the files are just instructions for how to do that.

Comment: I added an example, maybe that helps understanding.